# Flash Load external Video and Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, video, external

I have added an external video to a flash AS3 file using the normal sequence:

file> import> import video

The video is in an mp4 format and I have not set a skin on it. The file plays fine, but I would like it to loop once complete.

I tried gotoAndPlay(1), which appears to have returned to the beginning of the file, but has not restarted the video.

Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

use the following code

```
fvp.source=yourvideo
fvp.autoRewind=true
fvp.addEventListener(VideoEvent.AUTO_REWOUND, videoPlayAgain, false, 0, true)
function videoPlayAgain( event:VideoEvent):void
{
 event.target.play()
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what format the 'yourvideo' needs to be in. Would it be the name of the file (filename.mp4) or the instance name (myVideo). Does each line need ; at the end?

Comment: yourvideo is the name of your video.i have used for .flv video files and it should also work for .mp4 files.

Comment: hi, what's fvp?